# Search a drop down list for items containing specific text

Tags: javascript

I want to do a "contains" searching on a list using JavaScript. For example I have a list:

```
AM Polland
AM Certification.
AR Ams
```

Now I have a text box and I have done searching (Starting with) like if I type "A" all the records comes starting with A.

But I want if I type "Pol" then "AM Polland" record should show.

actually i have a big picklist...above that i have a textbox..i want to do seaching based on the letters i type in that textbox.but i want contains searching not starts with.

I don't know how to do that, I am kind of learning JavaScript. Please help with some code.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any auto complete plugin?

Comment: actually i have a big picklist...above that i have a textbox..i want to do seaching based on the letters i type in that textbox...i dont want auto plug in....

Comment: Do you have all the items preloaded to existing drop down list in your page?

Comment: yes..they are preloaded.

Comment: So please show some code and we can help you change it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin in jQuery UI. You can make a better use of it.

#### Features:

1. Default functionality
2. Accent folding
3. Categories
4. Combobox
5. Custom data and display
6. Multiple values
7. Multiple, remote
8. Remote JSONP datasource
9. Remote datasource
10. Remote with caching
11. Scrollable results
12. XML data parsed once

#### Simple Example:

```
<!doctype html>
 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your current code just checks the `substr` of the appropriate length. What you need for this is a regex.

```
// first, a helper function to escape regex characters. Source: phpJS
function preg_quote(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[.\\+*?\[\^\]$(){}=!<>|:\-]/g, '\\$&');
}
// create the regex (assuming "input" is the variable containing the search string)
var regex = new RegExp(preg_quote(input)), i;
// now search for it (assuming "list" is the array of strings containing the data)
for( i in list) {
    if( list.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if( list[i].match(regex)) {
            // it's a match! do something with it
        }
    }
}
```